# How can I see the inside of a cylinder in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I place my camera inside of a cylinder but I am not able to see it. All I can see is the outside of it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out! You have to add a material to the cylinder, then select Shader/Legacy Shaders/Particles/Alpha Blended.

Comment: There should be a "StandardDoublesided" shader availabe in unity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double sided materials (which will render twice) you can just flip your mesh (aka invert normals).

Inverting normals is performed by taking the triangles array which contains indexes of vertexes that the mesh is referring to when renderig triangles.

A simplest code that does it looks kind of like this:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MeshInverter : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        var triss = meshFilter.sharedMesh.triangles;
        var normals=meshFilter.sharedMesh.normals;
        for (int i=0;i<normals.Length;i++)
            normals[i]=-normals[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < triss.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            int temp = triss[i * 3 + 1];
            triss[i * 3 + 1] = triss[i * 3];
            triss[i * 3] = temp;
        }
        Mesh mesh=Instantiate(meshFilter.sharedMesh);
        mesh.triangles=triss;
        mesh.normals=normals;
        meshFilter.mesh=mesh;
    }
}
```

It will make the inside of the capsule visible in play mode

Comment: you should include flipping the normals as well `var normals = mesh.normals;
 for(var n = 0; n < normals.Length; n++)
 {
     normals[n] = -normals[n];
 }
 mesh.normals = normals;` (https://answers.unity.com/questions/624755/how-to-inverse-the-mesh.html)

Comment: And you can do it in one line ;) `mesh.triangles = mesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();`

Comment: @derHugo it doesn't quite compile but the idea is neat (and works once the syntax is corrected)

Comment: actually ... if is for lightning and rendering ... wouldn't it be enough to **only** flip the normals and don't touch the triangles at all? just curious ^^

Comment: @derHugo I just checked to be sure and no, just flipping normals just messes up the shading, but has no effect on the culling (which determines which face is camera facing face and which is backfacking)

Comment: yeah makes sense now that you say it, thanks for checking it anyway;)